# Lumen: How to delete a record from DB?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-routing

Using Lumen, I'm displaying "Tickets". Here's my `Tickets.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
<div>
    <p>{{ $ticket->id }}</p>
    <p>{{ $ticket->content }}</p>
    <button onclick="deleteTicket({{$ticket->id}})">Delete</button>
</div>
@endforeach
```

So essentially, each time someone clicks delete, it triggers this script:

```
<script>
    function deleteTicket(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/tickets/deleteTicket",
            data: id,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function () {
                console.log('deleted!');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

In my `routes.php`, I have this:

```
$app->post('tickets/deleteTicket','TicketsController@deleteTicket');
```

Finally, in my `TicketsController.php`, I have:

```
public function deleteTicket($id) {
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    $ticket->delete();

    return redirect('/tickets');
}
```

The problem I'm getting when I press the button (console):

> POST http://example.com/tickets/deleteTicket 404 (Not Found)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, and why that method isn't being found. Can anyone help out?

**EDIT-** I have changed my `routes.php` to:

```
$app->get('tickets/deleteTicket/{id}','TicketsController@deleteTicket');
```

My script looks the same but I changed the "type" to `get` rather than `post`.

If I visit, this site: `http://mysite/tickets/deleteTicket/1`, the ticket will be deleted, and it redirects to `tickets` page. But if the button is clicked, this error happens:

> http://MYSITE/tickets/deleteTicket?id=3 404 (Not Found)

At this point, I'm thinking that I just need to revise my AJAX call to the correct URL, but I want to make sure security is an issue.

Comment: Change your route: $app->post('/tickets/deleteTicket','TicketsController@deleteTicket');

Comment: @hizbul25 That is exactly what I have in my question.

Comment: What do I change it to?

Comment: This not exactly in your question.  $app->post('/tickets/deleteTicket','TicketsController@delete‌​Ticket'); I have added a '/' just starting of route. try with this. better come in chat.

Comment: @hizbul25 I did try putting a "/" at the beginning of the URL in `routes.php`. No change still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can try this :

routes.php

```
$app->get('tickets/deleteTicket/{id}','TicketsController@deleteTicket');
```

Okay here's your blade :
add class to button and remove the function on click. like this one :

```
<button class="delete" data-id="{{$ticket->id}}>Delete</button>
```

And  your script :

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({ 
       url : "tickets/deleteTicket/"+id+"",
       type : "get" or "post",
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data);    
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you return first the $id in your deleteTicket function. Like this 
public function deleteTicket($id) {
return $id;
}
To check if there's really an ID passed through the route

Comment: Yes. What I did instead was `console.log($id);` inside the `deleteTicket` function, the id is being passed through.

Comment: Hmm. Cann you change your url to url : "tickets/deleteTicket". I've removed the first forward slash.

Comment: That is the way it's been this entire time. Still no change.

Comment: Try this in your routes.php : $app->get('tickets/deleteTicket/{id}, 'TicketController@deleteTicket'); I've tried on my pc and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121309/discussion-between-ruther-bergonia-and-volcovmeter).

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work, still have a 404. Also, you just put `TicketController` instead of `TicketsController`

Comment: have you changed the type in ur ajax function? type : 'get' and still in your route $app->get('tickets/deleteTicket/{id}, 'TicketsController@deleteTicket');

Comment: to be sure, access the url directly in your browser for example : www.sample.com/tickets/deleteTicket/3 -> 3 here is the ticket id, replace it with the any id that you have in your database from tickets table

Just make sure, you followed the code I gave you.

Comment: When I changed the ajax function to get as well, I get same error, but different URL: `http://IPADDRESS/tickets/deleteTicket?id=1`

Comment: Can you give the full url for that? So I can test it here and see the actual errors. If you would allow. Thanks

And what's the error when you're accessing it directly in the browser?

Comment: Boom. I just edited the question. Please take a look. I think there's some progress.

Comment: Look as if, I type out `http://MYSITE/tickets/deleteTicket/3` it works, but if I change my AJAX to `url: "/tickets/deleteTicket/" + id;`, the URL if not found in the get call or post call.

Comment: Change it to like this url : "/tickets/deleteTicket/"+id+" ",

Answer (score 0):

**Too things you must to change** 
***- In JS***

```
url: "/tickets/deleteTicket", // Try change to your full URL with http://
data: id, // Change to data: "id="+id,
```

***- In Controller***

```
public function deleteTicket(Request $request) {
    $ticket = Ticket::find($request->id);
    $ticket->delete();

    return redirect('/tickets');
}
```

Comment: I just tried changing to full URL with the `data` adjustment, still not finding that URL.

Comment: Change POST to GET and access directly from browser to make sure everything work fine except the url

Comment: Can you please give me an example, this is an IP address.

Comment: Change route to `$app->get('/tickets/deleteTicket','TicketsController@delete‌​Ticket');`, write something in Controller and access `http://example.com/tickets/deleteTicket `  directly through browser